# PHP pack/unpack error

Tags: php, pack

I have to convert an old "encrypted" data to a proper encryption algorithm from an old system.  I have this code:

```
 function unpackString($s,$l){
      $tmp=unpack('c'.$l,$s);
      $return=NULL;
      foreach($tmp as $v){
          if($v>0){
              $return.=chr($v);
          }
      }
      return $return;
  }
  function packString($s,$l){
      $return=NULL;
      for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++){
          $return.=pack('c',ord(substr($s,$i,1)));
      }
      return $return;
  }

  $string='StackOverflow Is AWESOME';
  $l=strlen($string);

  $encoded=packString(base64_encode($string),$l);
  $decoded=base64_decode(unpackString($encoded,$l));


  echo "\n".$decoded."\n";
```

Why the output shows `StackOverflow Is A` and not `StackOverflow Is AWESOME`

Comment: Is your spacebar broken?

Comment: Consider using "c*" instead of trying to hard-code the length in there.  If you know the whole string is going to be passed in, might as well tell it to process the whole thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

base64 encoding expands the size of a string by about 33%. You're passing in the length of the ORIGINAL string, not the base64 encoded one:

```
StackOverflow Is AWESOME  - 24 chars plaintext
U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdyBJcyBBV0VTT01F - 32 chars base64 encoded
```

So you're chopping off 8 characters, leaving you with

```
U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdyBJcyBB
```

which decodes to

```
StackOverflow Is A
```